# The file can't be merged back to the trunk from my branch after I delete the file in the trunk

Tags: svn, merge, branch, conflict, delete-file

I got a problem about merge file from my branch to the trunk

Originally, I got three files in my trunk:  file1.m, file2.m, file3.m
And I got the same three files in my branch.

After I delete file "file3.m" in my trunk, and make some change in my branch.
I try to merge the branch back to my trunk, but the file "file3.m" didn't show up in my trunk project.

How can I get the file "file3.m" back to my trunk?

Moreover, sometime it will tell me there are some conflicts in file "file3.m" in my trunk after I merge the branch, but I can't even find the file "file3.m" in my trunk, how can it be conflicted at all?